# How to use forward slash in website

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a website that runs on a URL, for example www.mywebsite.com. I want to be able to host different users profiles at URLs like www.mywebsite.com/userID . How can I use the same page for all possible userID s, so the website can show the same page, but it pulls specific data from my database just for that userID?
Sorry that this is probably a very basic question.

Comment: you could request and display on the pageand at the same time use 
`var temp = { foo: "bar" };`
`window.history.pushState(temp, "User Profile: " + userID, "www.mywebsite.com/" + userID);`

Comment: @TimWhiting It's not that it's a basic question, it's that it doesn't fit the StackOverflow criteria of showing what you've tried. It's very hard to find a place to ask a question where you don't even know where to start. If you plan on using javascript like you've tagged Google Node and Express. Most basic tutorials cover this kind of concept.

Answer (score 2):

You have tagged the question as JavaScript, and while this is certainly possible in JS (see single-page applications), this is more traditionally achieved (and probably easier for someone unfamiliar) with server-side processing.

## Client Side Approach

The usual flow of web browsing is as follows:

- User clicks on link
- Browser sends request to server
- Server processes request and sends response
- Browser renders new response
- User sees new page

Javascript SPAs effectively hijack this flow at stage 1 - when you click on a link the browser does not send a response to the server.  Instead, the SPA (more specifically it's router) decides how to manipulate the currently loaded page to show the required view.

In your scenario, the SPA would make an ajax call to an API, which could then respond with JSON data containing details of the user.  The SPA would then use this response to update the page.

The most common SPA frameworks in use are ReactJs and Angular (although probably look at Angular 2.0) only.

## Server Side Approach

Your standard webserver (e.g. Apache, nginx) takes the 'userID' part of the URL and tries to find a file on disk at that location, and send it as a response to the HTTP request.  Obviously you are not going to create a file for each userID, so we need a way to tell the server to send the same file for every request.  This is done with URL rewriting.  This turns the requested URL e.g.

`http://www.example.com/553`

into something the server can work with, e.g.

`http://www.example.com/users.php?id=553`

Depending on your server this is achieved in different ways, Apache uses the mod_rewrite module.

Now you only need one PHP file - `users.php` - which accesses the URL's query parameter and performs a database search based on the id it finds. (N.B. be certain to look at input sanitization).  The PHP file then uses the database results to populate the response page it sends.